# Is there a way to generate $4\times 4$ unitary matrices uniformly?

Tags: matrices, lie-groups

$SU(2)$ has a nice parametrzed representation which allows me to iterate over the parameters and generate the matrices. Is there anything similar for $SU(4)$? I came across the generators but not sure as to how to use them to generate matrices that span the entitre space of $U(4)$.
Ref : http://www.ejtp.com/articles/ejtpv10i28p9.pdf

I also came across a mathematica code that does generate random matrices but I am looking for a methodical iterative way to go about it similar to $SU(2)$. 
Ref : https://www.google.co.in/url?cad=rja&cd=1&esrc=s&q=&rct=j&sa=t&sig2=s_Df5GaAh0Uxh5dSQegW9Q&source=web&uact=8&url=http%3A%2F%2Fhome.lu.lv%2F%7Esd20008%2Fpapers%2Fessays%2FRandom%2520unitary%2520%5Bpaper%5D.pdf&usg=AFQjCNHhDcOWxktNNYeJsAYEIIW7g4l0NA&ved=0ahUKEwjUzqOVtKHUAhXLPo8KHR6aDr8QFggnMAA

PS : I do not understand Lie groups and just looking for a method to iterate over the space of $U(4)$ efficiently.

Comment: The second reference itself explains this partially: "It turns out that one can generalize this idea to sample uniformly from $\textrm{U}(n)$ (see [6]). The main idea is to decompose an $n \times n$ unitary as a product of two-level unitaries $G(i, j) \in \textrm{U}(n)$ known as Givens rotations [8, 12]. Each Givens rotation $G(i, j)$ is just the $n \times n$ identity matrix with elements at positions $ii, ij, ji, jj$ replaced by an arbitrary $2 \times 2$ unitary matrix."

Comment: @Travis Yes, they also give a mathematica code to sample unifromly. This is slightly different. For example : In the case of SU(2), one can iterate over a set of angular parameters (first ref has this), to span the entire space. I wish to search the space for matrices which satisfy certain other conditions. So, it would be ideal if I can have some iterative way wherein the search depends on the granularity of iteration and not randomization (as done in mathematica code).

Comment: You want the generic cubic polynomial in the generator, analog of the quadratic for 3x3 [SU(3) matrices](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/280082211_Elementary_formula_for_the_fundamental_SU3_representation)?

Comment: @CosmasZachos I am sorry but I do not understand your question and your result. I am not a mathematician. But I see what you are trying to reference might be helpful. In simple terms, is there an explicit formula for generating U(4) matrices whereby I can vary the parameters of this formula to span the entire space? I hope the question is clear. I just wish to iterate over allowed range of parameters and generate all the matrices. Thank you for your response.
PS : I wish to search for the optimal quantum operator for a specific task and wish to do this numerically and iteratively.

Comment: I see... You really don't need to start from the generators, then. You want a rich ensemble of the 15-dim space of 4x4 unitary matrices. I know lattice gauge theorists do this routinely, but I don't know what their most efficient algorithms are...

Comment: @CosmasZachos Yes, that is correct. I need an ensemble that covers the space fairly uniformly. Thank you for the information.

Comment: Just incase someone lands here in future :
The closest answer lies in this paper - 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5904.pdf

Thanks to Eric Anson who replied here :
https://www.quora.com/Is-there-a-way-to-generate-4x4-unitary-matrices-uniformly-See-details/answer/Alon-Amit?srid=p3cX